# hasattr telling lies? (AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute '__annotations__')

Tags: python-3.x

The following code

```
class Foo:
    def bar(self) -> None:
        pass

foo = Foo()
if hasattr(foo.bar, '__annotations__'):
    foo.bar.__annotations__ = 'hi'
```

crashes with

```
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute '__annotations__'
```

How can this happen?

Comment: hasattr return ``True`` if ``getattr(object, name)`` don't raise, and when you do ``getattr(foo.bar, "__annotations__")`` you get ``{'return':None}``. This is why hasattr(foo.bar, '__annotations__') return ``True``.

Comment: Seems Python bug to me.  `AttributeError: readonly attribute` would be more sensible error message here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The attribute error here is raised because you can't set **any** attribute on a method object:

```
>>> foo.bar.baz = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'baz'
```

The exception here is perhaps *confusing* because `method` objects *wrap a function object* and proxy attribute *read access* to that underlying function object.  So when attributes on the function exist, then `hasattr()` on the method will return `True`:

```
>>> hasattr(foo.bar, 'baz')
False
>>> foo.bar.__func__.baz = 42
>>> hasattr(foo.bar, 'baz')
True
>>> foo.bar.baz
42
```

However, you still can't set those attributes via the method, regardless:

```
>>> hasattr(foo.bar, 'baz')
True
>>> foo.bar.baz = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'method' object has no attribute 'baz'
```

So, just because the attribute can be *read* doesn't mean you can *set* it. `hasattr()` is speaking the truth, you just interpreted it to mean something different.

Now, if you tried to set the `__annotations__` attribute directly on the underlying function object you'd get another error message:

```
>>> foo.bar.__func__.__annotations__ = 'hi'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: __annotations__ must be set to a dict object
```

You would want to use a dictionary object here:

```
>>> foo.bar.__func__.__annotations__ = {'return': 'hi'}
>>> foo.bar.__annotations__
{'return': 'hi'}
```

However, because `__annotations__` is a **mutable** dictionary, it is just easier to directly manipulate the keys and values to that object, which is perfectly feasible to do via the method wrapper:

```
>>> foo.bar.__annotations__['return'] = 'int'
>>> foo.bar.__annotations__
{'return': 'int'}
```

Now, if you were hoping to set **per instance** annotations, you can't get away with setting attributes on method objects, because method objects are *ephemeral*, they are created just for the call, then usually discarded right after.

You would have to use custom method descriptor objects via a metaclass and re-create the `__annotations__` attribute for those each time, or you could instead pre-bind methods with a new function object that would be given their own attributes. You then have to pay a larger memory price:

```
import functools

foo.bar = lambda *args, **kwargs: Foo.bar(foo, *args, **kwargs)
functools.update_wrapper(foo.bar, Foo.bar)  # copy everything over to the new wrapper
foo.bar.__annotations__['return'] = 'hi'
```

Either way you [completely kill important speed optimisations made in Python 3.7](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#cpython-bytecode-changes) this way.

And tools that operate on the most important use case for `__annatotions__`, type hints, do not actually execute code, they read code statically and would completely miss these runtime alterations.

Comment: Great answer, as usual. Thank you. :)
Don't worry, I don't plan to actually change `__annotations__` of methods at runtime. I ran into this more by accident, but was confused by the error, so I wanted to find out only for understanding. Your explanation totally makes sense. However I think the error message could be a bit more obvious instead of `has no attribute`. ;)

Comment: @TobiasHermann: The problem there is that then `method` would have to implement a `__setattr__` hook that was just there to test if the attribute existed on the wrapped object, then adjust the error message of the `AttributeError` exception it throws. That's... going to lead to surprising semantics the moment its a custom object that's being wrapped.

Comment: @TobiasHermann: and that's aside from a discussion of the possible side effects and cost of the `hasattr()` call.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting an error. because `__annotations__` is a dictionary. If you want to change values you'll have to do it like this:

```
if hasattr(foo.bar, '__annotations__'):
    foo.bar.__annotations__['return'] = 'hi'
```

This will make the return value of your `foo.bar` be `hi` instead of `None`. The only thing I'm not sure about is how the `__annotations__` are protected, not allowing you to change them from a dict to string, but I suppose it's some internal check in the source.

**UPDATE**

For more control over the signature you can use the `inspect` module and get the Signature object of your class(or method) and edit it from there. For example

```
import inspect
sig = inspect.signature(foo.bar)
sig.return_annotation  # prints None (before modifying)
sig.replace(return_annotation="anything you want")
```

More on that [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#inspect.Signature)